# sending email in local with mailtrap.io

Tags: email, solspace-freeform

I'm following [this guide](http://www.nainteractive.com/notebook/use-mailtrap.io-to-safely-test-and-debug-email-with-expressionengine) for sending email in my local environment for testing my freeform's form, but I'm not using Focus Lab config overrides

I configured the email settings as in the screenshot, but it doesn't work
[image]

Have you any idea what the problem is? I'm on Windows 7 and I'm using WAMP

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested it with PHP Mail or Sendmail to see if that works? Are you getting any error messages back with regards to your SMTP attempts?

Comment: my mistake. I had to check emails in the inbox of mailtrip, instead of in my inbox